# What is the name of the typface in Casino-themes '777' designs?

Tags: font-identification

I think this font is commonly used in Casino-themed graphic designs but I don't know what the name of the typeface is.

[image: Casino 777 font]

What is the font name of the 777 in the picture? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Blues, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Comment: @Vincent thanks for the comment, i forgot to add details to my question. I've been searching the typeface for days. I tried some of the tools in the link you have given me before i posted this query. :(

Comment: Would a similar casino type font work or do you need this one exactly?

Comment: @Jenna a similar will do for now

Comment: The swept top to 7 means it's basically a [Clarendon](http://www.myfonts.com/search/clarendon/fonts/) -- try sampling a "7" with that collection. Because fruit-machines only have this one digit on the reels, it's probably specially-drawn, but I'm sure you can find something reasonably close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few examples with very similar 7s, found them on [dafont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=502&text=7) under the serif category.

[Pistilli Roman](http://www.dafont.com/pistilli-roman.font?text=7)

[image]

[K22 Didoni](http://www.dafont.com/k22-didoni.font?text=7)

[image]

[Postamt](http://www.dafont.com/postamt.font?text=7)

[image]

[Fette](http://www.dafont.com/fetteegyptienne.font?text=7)

[image]

[Chapaza](http://www.dafont.com/chapaza.font?text=7)

[image]